# Does $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This may be an obvious question but I'm just not thinking straight, thanks

The answer must be no

Comment: It is true if and only if $f(x) = \log(C-x) + D$ where $C,D$ are constants (of if $f$ is constant).

Comment: When you suspect something to be true, proving so may be difficult or even unreachable. Fortunately, when you suspect something to be false, all you have to do is find a single counterexample. In this case, it would be difficult to find a function for which this *was* true!

Answer (score 8):

Of course not !
Take for exemple 
$$f(x,y)=x,$$
then
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2=1,$$
but
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=0.$$

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, nope. But let's explore for which functions it *is* true. If the function is not linear, it has a second derivative that is not always zero, so the first step here is valid. (And if the function *is* linear, we can work out that it would have to be a constant function.)

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}
&=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\\
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}
&=1&\text{anitdifferntiate on both sides}\\
-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}
&=x+C_1\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
&=\frac{-1}{x+C_1}&\text{anitdifferntiate on both sides}\\
f(x)&=-\ln\left|x+C_1\right|+C_2(x)
\end{align}
$$
where $C_2$ is some function that is a constant value on $\left(-C_1,\infty\right)$ and a possibly different constant value on $\left(-\infty,-C_1\right)$. You could also write it as $$f(x)=-\ln\left|x+C\right|+D\frac{x+C}{|x+C|}+E$$

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. Pick any function you like and work out the RHS and LHS, and you will almsot always get two different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. To see this, let's consider an example (there are simpler examples...)
$$
f(x,y) = x^2y^2
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xy^2 \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 2y^2.
$$
And
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 = (2xy^2)^2 = 4x^2y^4. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f(x,y)=x$. Verification is left to you.